# Unrecognized character \x90 ERROR in perlcode.exe

Tags: perl

`Unrecognized character \x90 at line..`

I am getting above error while executing `perlcode.exe`, But when it is executed as Perl (i.e `perlcode.pl`) it works like a charm. And, I am surprised I haven't seen any such error in Google. Any help appreciated.

The input file is a LaTeX file which may or may not have Unicode.

1. Why is `.pl` working, but `.exe` is not working?
2. What is meant by the ERROR: `Unrecognized character \x90 at line..`?

Note that `use utf8;` is used in the Perl script.

Comment: You cannot rename perl scripts to `.exe` and expect it to work. What is your motivation for the .exe extension? As for the other question, what does the script do? Why is it important that the input is latex?

Comment: May I know whats the error shows ( a full line ) while running the tool.

Comment: `perl -w perlcode.exe` sure not works

Comment: `perl` throws that error when it sees character `0x90` in the source code or regex pattern where it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I wasn't thinking straight. I had compiled the .pl file with perl2exe but was running the command

```
perl c:\tmp\myexe.exe
```

Obviously you don't need to have perl at the start - just run the exe

Answer (score 0):

To change the perl code to an .exe file, you'll need to compile it. If you are saying that the pl code works allright, but the exe not, maybe that it's the issue.

One of the options is to use pp to do it. You can find it [here](http://search.cpan.org/~autrijus/PAR-0.85_01/script/pp#NAME).

Answer (score 0):

its a typo mistake which has been made in a batch file while calling exe.